# Error inflating layout DSLV library

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

When I am launching my application, I am getting the error:

```
04-29 10:20:15.655: E/AndroidRuntime(24548): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
```

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingTop="7dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:dividerHeight="5dp"
dslv:drag_enabled="true"
dslv:collapsed_height="2dp"
dslv:drag_scroll_start="0.33"
dslv:max_drag_scroll_speed="0.5"
dslv:float_alpha="0.6"
dslv:slide_shuffle_speed="0.3"
dslv:track_drag_sort="false"
dslv:use_default_controller="true"
dslv:sort_enabled="false"
dslv:remove_enabled="true"
dslv:remove_mode="flingRemove"
android:background="#E5E5E5" />
```

Does anyone know whats causing the issue? When I attempt to specify the full url "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mobeta.android.demodslv", the project does not compile.

Answer (score 7):

change  xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

to below line

xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.mobeta.android.dslv"